# Validate Gridview

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview

I have gridview with template fields(textbox,dropdown list,...) and I use required field validators for the textbox and dropdownlist where I make the validation on textchanged and dropselected index changed my problem is that the validation happend on all rows not just on the row where i change the text
any idea?

validation is going to be fired for all dropdowns residing into other rows. how can i orevent this?

thanks

this the code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="uxCountSheetView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="uxCountSheetView_RowDataBound"
             AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15" OnPageIndexChanging="uxCountSheetView_PageIndexChanging" ShowFooter="true">
            <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uxItems" runat="server" Width="100" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="All" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="uxItems_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator3"
          ControlToValidate="uxItems" Display="Static" ValidationGroup="All" InitialValue="" Width="100%" runat="server">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>          </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AfterQuantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="uxAfterQuantity" ValidationGroup="All" CausesValidation="true" OnTextChanged="uxAfterQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="uxFilterAfterQuantity" runat="server" FilterType="Custom, Numbers"
             TargetControlID="uxAfterQuantity" ValidChars="."></cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator6"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          ControlToValidate="uxAfterQuantity"
          Display="Static" ValidationGroup="All"
          InitialValue="" Width="100%" runat="server"></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Difference"></Columns></asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you postback your form when a row selected, you can set your currentrow's validator controls' ValidationGroup to an active text, and all other validation controls at other rows should have ValidationGroup inactive.

And also set your submit button's ValidationGroup to active text that causes validation.

This will allow your submit button to validate only validators with the active ValidationGroup.

Answer (score 1):

check this link to validate controls in gridview with a validator

http://www.opexsolution.com/category/technical-corner/

go to Using Validators in gridview control Part I topic

Comment: The page you link to is now showing a 404 error. I suggest that in future you don't simply link to the answer but also give a bit of a description of the answer right here in your answer.